# How to optimally, programmatically, execute multiple SELECT queries?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Thanks in advance, and apologies if this is already covered.

Here is an example of an unoptimized (and unsafe) method:

```
        string[] ExampleInput = { "foo", "bar", "daily", "special" };
        int[] ReturnData = new int[ExampleInput.GetUpperBound(0)];

        SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("FooBar Connection String");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader reader;

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

        for (int i = 0; i <= ExampleInput.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [int] FROM [table] WHERE [string] = '" + ExampleInput[i] + "'; ";
            sqlConnection1.Open();
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                    ReturnData[i] = reader.GetInt32(0);
            }

            reader.Close();
            sqlConnection1.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could perform an `IN` operator on your query, for sample to execute a single query. I did some changes on your code to use the `using` block for unmanaged objects that implements `IDisposable` interface (remove from memory). For sample (see the comments):

```
var ExampleInput = { "foo", "bar", "daily", "special" };
List<int> tempReturnData = new List<int>();

using (var sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("FooBar Connection String"))
{
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand()) 
    {
        cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

        // generate something like 'foo','bar','daily', 'special' into the string
        string parameterValue = string.Concat("'", string.Join("','", ExampleInput), "'");

        // execute the single query
        cmd.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT [int] FROM [table] WHERE [string] IN ({0});",  parameterValue);

        sqlConnection1.Open();

        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) 
        {
            // add all ements on the listof integers
            while (reader.Read())
                tempReturnData.Add(reader.GetInt32(0));        
        }

        reader.Close();
        sqlConnection1.Close();
    }
}

// get the final list of ints as array
int[] ReturnData = tempReturnData.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to run multiple queries and get their results. The approach included in your question is one method, though I would recommend you keep the connection open and just make new commands.

Since `SqlConnection`,`SqlCommand`, and `SqlDataReader` objects are disposable, you should properly handle these objects by using the `using` clause. The disposal of these objects will handle the cleanup of any unmanaged resources and will close the necessary components.

Here is the updated code based on your existing method.

```
string[] ExampleInput = { "foo", "bar", "daily", "special" };
int[] ReturnData = new int[ExampleInput.GetUpperBound(0)];

using (SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("FooBar Connection String")) 
{
    sqlConnection1.Open();

    for (int i = 0; i <= ExampleInput.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
    {         
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [int] FROM [table] WHERE [string] = '" + ExampleInput[i] + "'; ";

            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                    ReturnData[i] = reader.GetInt32(0);
            }
        }            
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could concatonate your queries into a single string and use the SqlDataReader's `NextResult` method.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.nextresult%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396